# Sliding binding correcton

Tags: geometry, classicthesis, booklet, binding

I'm printing a document which is typeset as an A5 booklet version of my thesis (`classicthesis`, `scrreprt` class). I'm printing it on A4 paper and bind it myself with some common office gadgets. Now the problem is that the papers in the middle will get pushed outside due to how the whole thing is folded.

I would like to apply about -0.4 mm binding offset correction (in the same sense how BCOR works) in steps at each 4th page (so that each leaf of paper would have consistent binding corrections). Is there an automated way to do this in LaTeX?

I realize this could be possible manually using the `geometry` package, but I'm already using `\areaset` elsewhere and I'm told those two don't mix well.

**EDIT**:

So as I said, the pages are A5 but are printed on A4 paper, folded in half and stapled:
[image]

The problem I want to fix is this:
[image]

I want to cut the edge of the booklet off, so that all the papers are aligned. This consequently shortens the outer margin of the pages, but more in the middle and less at the outside. Hence the need for changing the binding correction.

I'm currently typesetting this as a single sided A5 document which I print as "booklet, double sided, flip at the short side" in my printer settings, which puts four pages on a single leaf of paper. That's why I need to increase the correction each four pages (although not so important, the 0.1 mm shift would likely be imperceptible -- but I'd know and it would wake me up in the middle of the night).

Comment: Exactly, either `geometry` *or* `typearea`, not both. You already mention `BCOR`, which does the job. But i don't understand why you print on A4 and bind A5 and why you need only every 4th page adjusted. I also don't understand why papers get pushed outside and you need a negative binding correction. Usually, you need a correction greater 0 because you need that space for binding.

Comment: I'll take a picture.

Comment: I don't know that it is traditional to compensate in this way. Usually, signatures are composed of a small enough number of pages for differences to be negligible. The pages are traditionally cut to create a smooth edge, but I don't know that the inner margins are changed to compensate. I don't really recommend doing this in LaTeX. Contrary to what @Johannes_B 's comment might suggest, there really isn't any ready-made mechanism to do this provided by any class or package except `zwpagelayout`. I've never used it, but it seems to support something like this. However, you would need to switch.

Comment: That is really for leaflets, though, where it is likely to be more significant. As I say, I am not sure this is traditional in book binding.

Comment: @cfr This is not a questioni about book binding, so BCOR won't help. I am not aware that there is a solution at hand. I would just print it on A5 paper and then do the binding (maybe with the help of a copy shop). But folding and stapling? No way. This gets very ugly very quickly. As seen in the photos.

Comment: @Johannes_B The best quality books, bound the traditional way, are folded and the signatures sewn. I agree that folding and stapling is likely to be ugly.

Comment: @Johannes_B and cfr: Sure a thread stitching is much better but also quite expensive. There’s the cheaper (and not that robust) adhesive binding but for magazines/booklets with not that many pages stapling is an option to. And in that case it is not uncommon to compensate the creep (German: _Bundzuwachs_).

Comment: @theswine: “but I'd know and it would wake me up in the middle of the night” – I’m sorry to tell you that you _pay_ for this correction by changing the inner margins, and then you may wake up because they aren’t the same in the whole document ;-) … in other words it is alway a compromise …

Comment: @cfr This is meant to be cheap, they are for a Ph.D. defense which lasts about an hour and they will be discarded afterward. And there needs to be 15 of those. I was just trying to make it look a bit more decent without increasing the price.

Comment: @Tobi I understand that, but it is by choice. I assume that the reader will have the margins perpendicular to his view but will look at the binding of the book under an angle due to the bending of the paper and thus in there the error is less noticeable. On the other hand, it should be possible to be a perfectionist about it and also keep the middle margin, effectively making the text area a bit more narrow on the pages in the middle.

Comment: I think even worrying about this for a PhD defence is bizarre. If this is what will keep you awake at night, then I really don't know what to say. (Which is fine, obviously.)

Comment: @theswine: yea thats (inner margin less noticeable than outer) is a good point. However if you want to make ist perfect use another binding type ;-) how many pages does your booklet have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s a two step solution I blogged this month (german: [*Booklets erzeugen*](http://tobiw.de/tbdm/booklets-erzeugen)):

1. make you document in single pages (A5) as you already do
2. use the following code to impose a booklet

```
\documentclass[
   paper=296mm:210mm,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{calc}
   \tikzset{
      every node/.style = {
         inner sep = 0pt,
         outer sep = 0pt,
      }
   }

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l_booklet_sheets_int
\int_new:N \l_booklet_counter_int
\int_new:N \l_booklet_total_pages_int
\int_new:N \l_booklet_total_pages_to_four_int
\dim_new:N \l_booklet_creep_dim

\cs_new:Npn \booklet_get_page:nn #1#2 {
   \int_compare:nT { ( #1 ) <= \l_booklet_total_pages_int } {
      \includegraphics [
         width = 0.5\paperwidth,
         height = \paperheight,
         keepaspectratio,
         page = #1,
      ] { #2 }
   }
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \MakeBooklet } { O{0mm} m } {
   \file_if_exist:nTF { #2 .pdf } {
      \int_zero:N \l_booklet_counter_int
      \dim_zero:N \l_booklet_creep_dim
      \pdfximage { #2 .pdf }
      \int_set:Nn \l_booklet_total_pages_int
         { \the \pdflastximagepages }
      \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { \l_booklet_total_pages_int } { 4 } != 0 } {
         \int_set:Nn \l_booklet_total_pages_to_four_int
            { \l_booklet_total_pages_int + 4 - \int_mod:nn { \l_booklet_total_pages_int } { 4 } }
      } {
         \int_set_eq:NN \l_booklet_total_pages_to_four_int \l_booklet_total_pages_int
      }
      \int_set:Nn \l_booklet_sheets_int
         { \l_booklet_total_pages_to_four_int / 2 }
      \int_do_while:nn { \l_booklet_counter_int < \l_booklet_sheets_int } {
         \clearpage
         \int_incr:N \l_booklet_counter_int
         \begin{tikzpicture}[remember~picture, overlay]
            \clip (current~page.north) rectangle (current~page.south~east);
            \node [anchor = west] at ($
               (current~page.center)
               -
               (\dim_use:N \l_booklet_creep_dim, 0)
            $) {
               \booklet_get_page:nn
                  { \int_use:N \l_booklet_counter_int }
                  { #2 }
            };
         \end{tikzpicture}
         \begin{tikzpicture}[remember~picture, overlay]
            \clip (current~page.north~west) rectangle (current~page.south);
            \node [anchor = east] at ($
               (current~page.center)
               +
               (\dim_use:N \l_booklet_creep_dim, 0)
            $) {
               \booklet_get_page:nn
                  { \int_eval:n { \l_booklet_total_pages_to_four_int - \l_booklet_counter_int + 1 } }
                  { #2 }
            };
         \end{tikzpicture}
         \clearpage
         \int_incr:N \l_booklet_counter_int
         \begin{tikzpicture}[remember~picture, overlay]
            \clip (current~page.north~west) rectangle (current~page.south);
            \node [anchor = east] at ($
               (current~page.center)
               +
               (\dim_use:N \l_booklet_creep_dim, 0)
            $) {
               \booklet_get_page:nn
                  { \int_use:N \l_booklet_counter_int }
                  { #2 }
            };
         \end{tikzpicture}
         \begin{tikzpicture}[remember~picture, overlay]
            \clip (current~page.north) rectangle (current~page.south~east);
            \node [anchor = west] at ($
               (current~page.center)
               -
               (\dim_use:N \l_booklet_creep_dim, 0)
            $) {
               \booklet_get_page:nn
                  { \int_eval:n { \l_booklet_total_pages_to_four_int - \l_booklet_counter_int + 1 } }
                  { #2 }
            };
         \end{tikzpicture}
         \dim_set:Nn \l_booklet_creep_dim {
            #1 * \l_booklet_counter_int / 2
         }
      }
   } {
      \Huge
      \noindent \textbf { Error! } \\
      File ~ \texttt { #2 .pdf } ~ not ~ found.
   }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

% #1 = shift per sheet (= thickness of paper, see below) [optional]
% #2 = filename without suffix (must be a PDF)
\MakeBooklet[1mm]{singe-pages}

\end{document}
```

The paper size of the printing sheets is given as class option `paper=b:h` with `b` = 2 × width of close booklet width and `h` = booklet hight. Then one can simply copy the implementation code and use `\MakeBooklet`. Run `pdflatex` (at least) twice to get the correct positions.

*You can finde details about the implementation in my german blog article, linked above …*

---

**How to calculate the shift per page?**

The shift of the most inner (middle) pages compared to the outer (first and last) pages – the *creep* - can be calculated with this equation:

creep = (count of pages incl. cover – 4) ÷ 4 × thickness of paper
creep = (count of sheets – 1) × thickness of paper

The shift for pages on a certain sheet – lets call it *v* – with this one:

v = creep ÷ (count of sheets – 1) × (sheet number – 1)
v = thickness of paper × (sheet number – 1)

Where “page” refers to the pages of the single paged (A5) document and “sheet” to the printed (A4) paper sheets.